# Using effects without dry/wet parameter in Cubase

Tags: effects, cubase, automation

I have 2 tracks that I need to filter for, say, the first 30 seconds using one of the cubase builtin filters. I'm having problem figuring out how can I manage to do this using automations. I've tried with sends and insert effects, but there's no way to set dry/wet.

I can bypass the problem creating one track that is filtered and another one for the non-filtered parts, but this seems kind of weird to me.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much ;)
Ciao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take the aux channel route to do this myself.

Set up an aux channel with just your filter on it and have it take it's input from an aux buss. Lets say it's Aux Buss 1 as the input. Since there's no wet-dry blend on the filter VST there's no need to set it to 100% wet.

On the channel you want to filter for a short period of time, add a pre-fader send to Aux Buss 1.

Now open your curve editor for the channel. You're going to create one curve that sets the send 1 level to be the appropriate send level to your aux channel for the first 30 seconds of the song, and then after that turns it down to -inf so nothing gets sent. Similarly you'll create a curve that sets the fader on the channel strip to be -inf for however long you're sending audio to the aux buss. And then have that curve jump the fader up to the appropriate level at the same moment the send value is being dropped to -inf.